# when setting random-motion of node to 0 gives error :"error when calling class $cls: $args" $..."

Tags: ns2

This is a wired network with `row*col` number of `nodes`. Since it is static i'm trying to set the `random-motion` to `0`.But when i run `ns wired.tcl 3 3 5 0.01` i get the below error. here the cmd parameters are

> ns `<filename>` `<no of rows>` `<no of col>` `<links>` `<cbr_interval>`

```
      (_o10 cmd line 1)
        invoked from within
    "_o10 cmd random-motion 0"
        invoked from within
    "catch "$self cmd $args" ret"
        invoked from within
    "if [catch "$self cmd $args" ret] {
    set cls [$self info class]
    global errorInfo
    set savedInfo $errorInfo
    error "error when calling class $cls: $args" $..."
        (procedure "_o10" line 2)
        (SplitObject unknown line 2)
        invoked from within
    "$node_($i) random-motion 0"
        ("for" body line 3)
        invoked from within
    "for {set i 0} {$i < [expr $num_row*$num_col]} {incr i} {
        set node_($i) [$ns node]
        $node_($i) random-motion 0
    }"
        (file "rough.tcl" line 34)
```

I'm running `ubuntu-18.04` and `ns-allinone-2.35` and this is the `wired.tcl` file

```
    set ns [new Simulator]
    $ns multicast
    set start_time 0.5
    set cbr_interval [lindex $argv 3]
    set num_row [lindex $argv 0]
    set num_col [lindex $argv 1]
    set x_dim 100
    set y_dim 100
    set grid 0

    set k 6
    set num_random_flow [lindex $argv 2]

    set traceFile [open wired.tr w]
    $ns trace-all $traceFile

    set nf [open out.nam w]
    $ns namtrace-all $nf

    #create-god [expr $num_row * $num_col ]

    proc  finish {} \
    {
        puts "finishing simulation"
        global ns nf traceFile
        $ns flush-trace
        close $traceFile
        close $nf
        #exec nam out.nam &
        exit 0
    }

    puts "start node creation"
    for {set i 0} {$i < [expr $num_row*$num_col]} {incr i} {
        set node_($i) [$ns node]
        $node_($i) random-motion 0; #problem
    }


    $ns at 5.0 "finish"
    puts "starting simulation"
    $ns run
```

Comment: May be the »» problem «« line isn't required. It's static. Nothing is moving. ... ... Random requires some settings → https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43679955/creating-random-wired-topology-for-given-arbitrary-number-of-nodes-on-ns2 ... ... ~3000 ex https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QbeW9Rtr_MU0JgfJiFQF-5N-5Okv8OGK/view?usp=sharing ... ← https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7S255p3kFXNSmRYb2lGcDRUdWs?usp=sharing

Comment: yes seen these resources.

Comment: isn't it necessary to set random-motion to 0 if i want it to be static? (i know i configured the nodes as static but shouldn't the random-motion flag be set to 0)